# Let $s(t)$ denote the position of a particle at time $t$, and let $v$ and $a$ be the velocity and acceleration

Tags: calculus

$$10+3^t-3t^2 , s(0)=-8 , s(2)=-7$$
Find the function describing the position of the particle
I tried:
$$10+3t-3t^2
=10t+(3/2)t^2-(t^3)
=5t^2+(1/2)t^2-(1/4)t^4$$
I got $c_2=8$
and then $c_1=-11$
and I put $5t^2+(1/2)t^3-(1/4)t^4-11t+8$
but it was incorrect

Comment: You don't indicate which of your expressions is $v$ or which is $a$, nor where $c_1$ and $c_2$ come in. Also, the $=$ sign is not a good way to indicate that the thing on the right is the integral of the thing on the left, if that in fact is what you meant. For help formatting the equations see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: is the second term of the function 3t or $3^t$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean $a(t)=10+3t-3t^2$

Then $$v(t)=10t+\frac{3t^2}{2} - t^3 +c_1$$

$$s(t)=5t^2+\frac{t^3}2 -\frac{t^4}4+c_1 t +c_2$$

By substituting t=0, $c_2=-8$

$s(2)=20+4-4+2c_1-8=-7$

$c_2=\frac{-19}2$